# How can i use a rewrite to hide files on IIS?

Tags: iis

i need to create a rewrite rule in IIS for this:

http://example.com/login.html
to
http://example.com/

I need to hide any filename that comes after the slash. I already created several rules, but none worked. Can anyone help me?

```
            <rule name="ocultar">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern=""                          ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern=""                         ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="url=&quot;/&quot;" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide any filename that comes after the slash, then the above method is not suitable for you, because you don't know the kind of all files, you can consider redirecting directly to the target url, the following rules can be used as a reference:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url=" http://example.com/" />
</rule>
```